# How to divide the data in while()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MYSQL code

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `merek` varchar(220) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(220) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `merek`, `url`) VALUES
(1, 'gelang', 'Untitled-1.jpg'),
(2, 'gelang', 'Untitled-2.jpg'),
(3, 'gelang', 'Untitled-3.jpg'),
(4, 'gelang', 'Untitled-4.jpg'),
(5, 'gelang', 'Untitled-5.jpg');
```

and PHP code

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $max = 2;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND()";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) and ($counter < $max)){
    $url=$row['url'];
    echo $url;
    echo "and";
    }
?>
```

Maybe the result will be like this

> `Untitled-2.jpg` and `Untitled-5.jpg` and

I want to split the `Untitled-2.jpg` and `Untitled-5.jpg`. So if `Untitled-2.jpg` , using `class="first"`. and `Untitled-5.jpg` use `class="second"`. Like this

```
       .....
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) and ($counter < $max)){
        $url=$row['url'];
        echo "<img src=$url class="first">;
        echo "<img src=$url class="second">;
        }
    ?>
```

Could I separate the data from a while() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment `$counter` value in `while` loop.

You can then add a condition to add desired classes. Below is the updated code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) and ($counter < $max)){
    $url=$row['url'];

    $class = ($counter == 0) ? 'first' : 'second';

    echo "<img src='$url' class='$class'>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer not satisfying this condition. if Untitled-2.jpg , using class="first". and Untitled-5.jpg use class="second"

Comment: That was an example posted by OP. You can see the sample DB values in the question. It wont work if it's hard coded.

Answer (score 2):

Add a counter in the while loop.

And check even odd condition.

```
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH) and ($counter < $max)){
  $url=$row['url'];
  $class = ($i%2 == 0) ? 'first' : 'second';
  echo "<img src='$url' class='$class'>";
  ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is shortest method**

Write this line in while loop and define $className in img tag.

> $className = ($url=='Untitled-2.jpg') ? 'first' :
>   (($url=='Untitled-5.jpg') ? 'second' : '');

**Modified :**

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND()";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $url = $row['url'];
        $className = ($url=='Untitled-2.jpg') ? 'first' : (($url=='Untitled-5.jpg') ? 'second' : '');
        echo "<img src=$url class=$className>";
    }
?>
```